# Postman collections: how do I save my requests into a collection?

Tags: postman

I'd like to create a collection of requests in order to save them and share with collaborators.

I havent find any button, menu action to add new requests (or current request ) to the newly created folder Collection?

not so much intuitive...

Comment: To summarize the answer below: you cannot do that.  Instead you repeat all of the steps you used to create your request in a brand new request, after you've opened or created the target collection.  To make it intuitive simply realize that the postman interface sucks, web or app, so when you want to do something that feels like basic functionality, your intuition should be that it's not supported.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this by hitting the X to close a request.  This popped up a warning asking if I want to save my request.  I clicked on Save Changes, which then allowed me to save my request to a collection.

Answer (score 4):

in the latest version of postman press ctrl+s -> and choose a collection to save into.

Comment: This works the first time, but what if I saved to the wrong collection and want to move it? Not sure how to do that easily.

Answer (score 3):

First create collection then create new request you will get option to save request "Save in existing collection" select your collection name and save it

Comment: I'm glad my text editor doesn't work that way.  I don't have to re-type the entire document to save it in a different file, which is convenient.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158513/2462531) answer, I would recommend enabling an auto-save option in the new Postman Version 10.18.9.

Go to Settings scroll down and enable `Autosave changes to your requests and collections` under Application.

Attached is the screenshot for the reference.

[image]